# How to correct in the Sinatra show block

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

Sorry, I will not use the specific expression in English.

`index.erb`

```
<h1>Hello World.</h1>
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
</ul>
<% capture_content :key do %>
 I'm Here.
<% end %>
```

`helpers`

```
def capture_content(key, &block)
  @content_hash = {}
  @content_hash[key] = block.call # this block contains erb all 
end
```

I just want `capture_content` in content

I hope expression is correct T_T

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want @content_hash[:key] = 'I'm Here'

Comment: Maybe the [Sinatra::ContentFor](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for.html) in the  Sinatra::Contrib does what your need?

Comment: @nemesv yes. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to write yourself the Sinatra equivalent of the Reails [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) helper then you don't need to.

Because there is an extension called [Sinatra::ContentFor](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for.html) which is part of the [Sinatra::Contrib](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/) project which does what you want.

From the [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for.html):

> Sinatra::ContentFor is a set of helpers that allows you to capture
>   blocks inside views to be rendered later during the request. The most
>   common use is to populate different parts of your layout from your
>   view.